# Android Development: Count EditText Lines on textChanged?

Tags: android, count, android-edittext, lines

How can I count the number of lines in an EditText?
Basically in my app I have line numbers and I wanted to make them update on textchange (I already have the textchangelistener set up).
Is this possible? :(

Thanks,
Alex!

Answer (score 12):

Lines can be differents:

- Visible lines: Wrapped text count as a new line...
- List item: Only lines with \r, \n, \r\n

First case (the easiest):

```
int nbLines = editText.getLineCount();
```

Second case:

```
        int nbLines = 0;
        StringReader     sr = new StringReader(editText.getText().toString());
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(sr);
        try { 
            while (lnr.readLine() != null){}
            nbLines = lnr.getLineNumber();
            lnr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            nbLines = editText.getLineCount();
        } finally {
            sr.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you define as "line number".
A line in your edittext in "GUI way", which includes the linebreaks your editview does? Or a line in a "coding way" of describing it (having \n at the end)?
First one will be quite hard to get, if even impossible. Second one: just count the numbers of \n in the text, plus add another 1 if there is something after the last \n.

Comment: By line numbers I mean the number of lines your EditText, I think counting the \n's is what I'm looking for, just trying a piece of code out now which will hopefully get me what I need! :)