# Android EditText real content height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in `Android`. It has long content and it scrolls into pages
How can I find the real height of content, not just the visible area?

I tried this, but it just gives height of visible area:

```
EditText editor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
.
.
.
double H=editor.getHeight();
```

not H is 1150, not 10000 or something like that which is real height of content.

Comment: please post what you have tried and what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do:

```
EditText tv = ...;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    totalHeight = Math.round((tv.getLineCount() * (tv.getLineHeight() + tv.getLineSpacingExtra()) *
                    tv.getLineSpacingMultiplier())) + tv.getCompoundPaddingTop() + tv.getCompoundPaddingBottom();
} else {
    totalHeight = tv.getLineCount() * tv.getLineHeight() + tv.getCompoundPaddingTop() + tv.getCompoundPaddingBottom();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following steps

count the lines in the edit text get help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787736/android-development-count-edittext-lines-on-textchanged)

after that calculate the height(includeing top padding) of single line then simply multiply that number to get the real height of the text inside the editText

Answer (score 0):

It was enough for me to call `EditText.getLayout().getHeight();`

I've just debugged an app where I need this functionality too:

```
        int contentHeight = view.getTextArea().getLayout().getHeight();
        int visibleAreaHeight = view.getTextArea().getHeight();
```

The values are:

```
contentHeight = 7531
visibleAreaHeight = 1408
```