# Android/Java EditableTextView Line Count

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I am trying to teach myself Android Java programming and I have started by attempting to create a simple text editor.

I wanted to have a line count down the left hand side like standard IDEs, and I couldn't really find anywhere on StackExchange or the internet on the definitive "best practice" way to do something like this.

So I created my own logic based on what I read, but I wanted to just check that this was the best and most efficient way to do it -- and also if this happens to help anyone out looking to do the same thing.

```
// START onCreate

// @mEditText = Main AutoCompleteTextView
// @mLineCount = Line Count TextView

mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  // Set current line variable
  private int currentLine;

  // Text Watcher
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // Before new text is inserted, get the current line count
    currentLine = mEditText.getLineCount();

  }
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    // Do nothing

  }
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {

    // Update Line Count
    // @mEditText: AutoCompleteTextView Input
    // @mLineCount: TextView Output
    // @currentLine: Integer
    updateLineCount(mEditText, mLineCount, currentLine);

  }
});

// END onCreate

public void updateLineCount(AutoCompleteTextView editText, TextView lineText, int currentLine){

  // Get updated Line Count
  int lineCount = editText.getLineCount();

  // If that Line Count exists and IS NOT the "before" Line Count (to stop repeating)
  if(lineCount > 0 && lineCount != currentLine){

    // If "before" Line Count is smaller, push Line Count up
    if(currentLine < lineCount){
      lineText.append(Integer.toString(lineCount) + "\n");
    }
    // Else if "before" Line Count is greater (ie. you have deleted a line), push Line Count down
    else {
      // Get Text of current lineText TextView, replace with a substring of
      // the current lineText TextView - the length of the deleted line
      // (ie. Line 9 = 1 Character + 1 for the line break; Line 10 = 2 Characters + 1 etc)
      lineText.setText(lineText.getText().toString().substring(0, lineText.getText().toString().length() - (Integer.toString(lineCount+1).length() + 1)));
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

So yeah, this is working fine -- but I am especially not sure about that last line -- Seems abit ... resource wasteful .. to be replacing the entire lineText TextView content each time a line is deleted.

Is there an anti-append that might work better in this situation?

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787736/android-development-count-edittext-lines-on-textchanged

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thanks. However I don't seem to be able to get that solution to work? When you delete a line it crashes. If I replace my `lineCount = editText.getLineCount()` with a public int function with the stringReader solution returning nbLines as an Integer -- it no longer updates my line count or handles delete?

Comment: did you try find out why it's crashed because your solution also use getLineCount(). So it not sure the crashing not occurs in your solution. Should to fix the simple solution rather than giving up and creating new one.

Comment: Got it working - but need to tweak the delete line count -- any suggestions?  Also how to handle Word Wrap -_-

Answer (score 0):

```
if(lineCount > 0 && lineCount != currentLine){
```

What happend if I select all text and delete all.
That will not meet the condition. 
So, mabe text line still display "5 lines" rather than "0 line"

Comment: Yep I've noticed that now when it deletes in bulk -- it misses line count. Attempting to tweak it to recount.